# How to get the content of a response header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response-headers

I want to get information from an HTTP response header. I do an HTTP request with the code example below.

```
var token = '123456'; 
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open('get', '/api/users/@me');
r.setRequestHeader('authorization', token);
r.send();
```

In the next step, the server checks if the request header includes a valid authorization token. If the token is valid the server sends a response.

```
app.get('/api/users/@me', (req, res) => {
  if (req.headers.authorization == '123456') {
    console.log(true);
    res.send('valid token!');
  }
});
```

Now I planned to get the request and display the content("valid token!") of it on the page, but I have no clue how I can do this.



I also tried to do the request like this:

```
fetch('https://localhost/api/users/@me', {
  headers: {
    authorization: '123456'
  }
}).then(result => {
  //...
})
```

But I don't find a way how to get the content out of it and display it on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.send('valid token!')` results in the "valid token" text being included in the response body. On the client side, use the `result.text()` method to read the text content of the response body. If this was a json response, you would have used `result.json()`.

```
fetch('https://localhost/api/users/@me', {
  headers: {
    authorization: '123456'
  }
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result.text())
})
```

Other methods similar to .text() are listed here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response